# zedgraph - creating masterpane in ASP.NET page

Tags: c#, asp.net, zedgraph

How do I call Zedgraph's function `masterPane.SetLayout()` from Web C# Application? 
Basically i'm stuck at step `myMasterPane.SetLayout(g, PaneLayout.SingleColumn);`
How do I create that variable g which is supposed to be a Graphic()

I tried `Graphics g = new Graphics();` and `Graphics g;`
none of these work.
new Graphics() gives me Error   2   The type 'System.Drawing.Graphics' has no constructors defined
and anyways I'm assuming this needs to be initialized somehow.

One important difference that I want to do vs the example below is that I want to go directly from my master pane to an image using
`masterPane.GetImage()`, my issue is I can't get that `masterpane` setup unless I find a way to call `myMasterPane.SetLayout()`

I found this article but  I can't get this working
http://zedgraph.org/wiki/index.php?title=Use_a_MasterPane_in_a_web_page

Comment: Please define what you mean when you say "none of these work"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The page you linked to shows exactly how to do this. Did you try their example?

The example gets the `Graphics` instance passed to it in the `RenderGraph` event handler.

Comment: When I try to call that function ZedGraphWebControllerHandler(function) 
I get 

Error 4 An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'TServer.ReportGeneration.OnRenderGraph(ZedGraph.Web.ZedGraphWeb, System.Drawing.Graphics, ZedGraph.MasterPane)'

Comment: @user: do you have any experience with .NET? `ZedGraphWebControllerHandler` is not a function. It's a delegate type. Please try to **exactly** duplicate the code in that article, and see what happens.